# linking to python library using EPD Canopy

Tags: enthought, epd-python, theano

Summary: I'm trying to install the theano python package, and the theano install can't find "-lpython2.7" in my EPD Canopy installation.

More details: Recently I installed the Enthought EPD Canopy python distribution (64-bit academic) in OS X 10.6.8.  Next I installed pip via "easy_install pip".

Next I installed Theano via "sudo pip install theano".  The install looks OK, but then python -c "import theano" fails.  The full output is at https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5548936, but it seems like the main point is:

Problem occurred during compilation with the command line below:

```
g++ -dynamiclib -g -D NPY_ARRAY_ENSURECOPY=NPY_ENSURECOPY -D NPY_ARRAY_ALIGNED=NPY_ALIGNED -D NPY_ARRAY_WRITEABLE=NPY_WRITEABLE -D NPY_ARRAY_UPDATE_ALL=NPY_UPDATE_ALL -D NPY_ARRAY_C_CONTIGUOUS=NPY_C_CONTIGUOUS -D NPY_ARRAY_F_CONTIGUOUS=NPY_F_CONTIGUOUS -fPIC -undefined dynamic_lookup -m64 -I/Users/rkeisler/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -o /Users/rkeisler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-10.8.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.3/lazylinker_ext/lazylinker_ext.so /Users/rkeisler/.theano/compiledir_Darwin-10.8.0-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-2.7.3/lazylinker_ext/mod.cpp -L/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.0.1160.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib -lpython2.7
```

## ===============================

ld: library not found for -lpython2.7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I've had some discussions with the theano google group, and the main message I get is to look for "libpython2.7.so", which I can't find.  I checked /Users/rkeisler/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/.  Inside is python2.7/os.py and python2.7/site-packages, but no "libpython*" files.

I also did a more thorough check for libpython* files.  The only things I could find were:

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/config/libpython2.5.a
/usr/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.a
/usr/lib/libpython.dylib
/usr/lib/libpython2.5.dylib
/usr/lib/libpython2.6.dylib
```

Finally, on the EPD Canopy package list, I see "libpython" listed.  However, when I try to install libpython using the Canopy package manager, "libpython" doesn't appear.  It's not an available package.  I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Theano. Theano should not be building `lazylinker_ext.so` with an explicit `-lpython2.7` flag. I will be following up with them. Try changing [this if test](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/f312d806a8b9efeb3980c7d212dfb90ee0a9fe0c/theano/gof/cmodule.py#L1454) to `if True:` and rebuilding Theano. It worked for me (at least letting me `import theano`).

Answer (score 0):

Following @RobertKern@ information, it is now fixed in the development version of Theano.

To update to the development version, do:

```
pip -U --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```